# テレビ台 vs テレビ to refer to the physical TV?

Tags: word-choice

To what extent does テレビ refer to the physical TV as opposed to the medium television? In other words, is it correct to say テレビを買う rather than テレビ台を買う?

Googling, I find equally many occurrences of both phrases, but significantly more using "台" if I replace テレビ with ラジオ.

Comment: In the [Google Japanese Web N-gram corpus](https://catalog.ldc.upenn.edu/LDC2009T08), I find 17208 results for `テレビを買う` and only 119 results for `テレビ台を買う`, which is a ratio of about 144:1.  Please remember that Google Search doesn't share result counts, only estimates which may be off by many orders of magnitude.  See [*Google counts may not be as reliable as you imagine*](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/522/google-counts-may-not-be-as-reliable-as-you-imagine) on meta for discussion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

テレビ台 stands for a "television stand" like [this one](http://amzn.to/1OwbVzd).

テレビ stands both for a "television" as a medium (e.g. テレビの力, テレビ朝日) and a "television set" (e.g. 液晶テレビ).

テレビ also stands for what in some English words wood be the prefix "tele-" or "video-", like テレビ会議 for a "videoconference".

台 is a counter for devices, so テレビ１台 means "one television set" and Google results could be affected by content containing such strings close to each other.

---

Additional information:

There is an older and more technical term [テレビ受像機](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%86%E3%83%AC%E3%83%93%E5%8F%97%E5%83%8F%E6%A9%9F) for a television set.

テレビジョン is a synonym for テレビ and describes medium, technology, and devices used for video transmission.

And "TV" as a broadcasting company is usually called [テレビジョン放送局](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%86%E3%83%AC%E3%83%93%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E6%94%BE%E9%80%81%E5%B1%80).